# php google analytics question about redirect with 'header'

Tags: php, redirect, google-analytics

Hay All.

I'm currently working on a 'checkout' system, the actual payment and stuff is done by a third party.

When a user checks out using a form it sends all the GET data to some other site, lets call this 'checkout.com'. So the query string is 'checkout.com?var=1&var2=2'.

What i want to do is put a page between my form and this call to checkout.com, i want to be able to log this with google analytics.

Can i use "header("location: checkout.com")"? or will the javascript not get called to log the page?

Do i need to use a HTML redirect? or a javascript redirect? or will the php redriect work properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Otherwise you could create a Google Analytics event tracking on the link that the user clicks / the form that the user fills out, in order to track the form submit / click.

See http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are using redirecting the browser, it won't execute the javascript, you'd have to use `window.location = 'checkout.com';` and call the google analytics script before the redirect.

I.E.

```
pageTracker._trackPageview('url of this page');
window.location = 'checkout.com';
```

checkout this [page](http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55529) for more information

Comment: However if a use then clicks 'back' in their browser they keep getting forwarded to 'checkout.com'?

Comment: yes but that's a behavior you cannot really avoid. if you wanna keep the google analytics approach it might be better to do some logging on your own database.

Comment: You might find that the tracker code doesn't get a change to run before the redirect line executes. Could try putting it in a timeout...   
setTimout("window.location = 'checkout.com',200");

Comment: unfortunately, the link is broken :(

Comment: here an updated [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackPageview) to be noted that the way the script work changed a great deal since 2009